# CSS :first-letter text-indent not working

Tags: html, css

I am learning about the pseudo-element `:first-letter` and tried to indent using the typical `text-indent` property and value but it is not working. Text indenting only works with `margin-left`. Any reason as to why?

HTML:

```
<p>Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it, 'and what is the use of a book,' thought Alice 'without pictures or conversations?'</p>
<p>As with text-indent, you can use pixel or em values to set the value of the margins.
You can also use percentages, but as with text-indent, the percentage is related to
the width of the paragraph’s containing element. Because it’s confusing to calculate
the space above and below a paragraph based on its width, it’s easier to stick with
either em or pixel values. CSS also provides a way of formatting just a part of a paragraph by using the :firstletter
and :first-line pseudo-elements (see Figure 6-16). Technically, these aren’t
CSS properties, but types of selectors that determine what part of a paragraph CSS
properties should apply to. With the :first-letter pseudo-element, you can create
an initial capital letter to simulate the look of a hand-lettered manuscript.</p>
```

CSS:

```
p:first-letter {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
    text-indent: 2em;
}
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/opshtvdy/

Comment: Hi, p{text-indent:2em}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `text-indent` on the first letter, when you should be using it on the `p` element itself. You are supposed to be using it on block elements. You can read more about `text-indent` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent)

Here's your fiddle with the appropriate CSS rules. https://jsfiddle.net/opshtvdy/6/

Answer (score 2):

use margin-left on :first-letter.

```css
p:first-letter {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: red;
 margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<p>Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it, 'and what is the use of a book,'
  thought Alice 'without pictures or conversations?'</p>
<p>As with text-indent, you can use pixel or em values to set the value of the margins. You can also use percentages, but as with text-indent, the percentage is related to the width of the paragraph’s containing element. Because it’s confusing to calculate
  the space above and below a paragraph based on its width, it’s easier to stick with either em or pixel values. CSS also provides a way of formatting just a part of a paragraph by using the :firstletter and :first-line pseudo-elements (see Figure 6-16).
  Technically, these aren’t CSS properties, but types of selectors that determine what part of a paragraph CSS properties should apply to. With the :first-letter pseudo-element, you can create an initial capital letter to simulate the look of a hand-lettered
  manuscript.</p>
```

or text-indent on p itself

```css
p:first-letter {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: red;
}
p {
  text-indent:2em;
  }
```

```html
<p>Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it, 'and what is the use of a book,'
  thought Alice 'without pictures or conversations?'</p>
<p>As with text-indent, you can use pixel or em values to set the value of the margins. You can also use percentages, but as with text-indent, the percentage is related to the width of the paragraph’s containing element. Because it’s confusing to calculate
  the space above and below a paragraph based on its width, it’s easier to stick with either em or pixel values. CSS also provides a way of formatting just a part of a paragraph by using the :firstletter and :first-line pseudo-elements (see Figure 6-16).
  Technically, these aren’t CSS properties, but types of selectors that determine what part of a paragraph CSS properties should apply to. With the :first-letter pseudo-element, you can create an initial capital letter to simulate the look of a hand-lettered
  manuscript.</p>
```